# Greatest lower bound implied least upper bound

Tags: real-analysis

In the baby Rudin there's a theorem that every ordered set with the least-upper bound
property also has the greatest-lower-bound property. I wonder if the converse is true?

I tried to prove it and it looks exactly the same as the least upper bound $\rightarrow$ greast lower bound theorem.

Comment: it should look the other way round, but yes, the idea is the same.

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent. The argument (with appropriate changes of inequality symbols and sup and inf switched) is basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

Let it be that order $(X,<)$ has the greatest upper bound property.

Then order $(X,>)$ has the least upper bound property and (as you said) consequently $(X,>)$ has the greatest upper bound property.

The last statement means exactly that order $(X,<)$ has the least upper bound property.